# References or resource recommendation for the mathematics concerning fission

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, critical-phenomena

I am working on a statistical problem that appears similar (in some respects...) to nuclear fission.

I am interested in the properties of a system undergoing fission around, or near, *delayed supercriticality*, but (being unfamiliar with the nuclear physics literature) I am having trouble finding a formal mathematical/physics treatment.

I am aware that the [Galton-Watson](http://www.stat.washington.edu/research/reports/2012/tr601.pdf)(*) branching process can be used to study simplified mechanics of nuclear fission, but is this the standard/modern approach?

References or resource suggestions would be most helpful.

(*)*Guttorp, Peter, and Michael D. Perlman. "Predicting Extinction or Explosion in a Galton-Watson Branching Process with Power Series Offspring Distribution." (2014).*

Comment: Did you search in Google? Try here: http://scholar.google.co.il/scholar?q=galton+watson+process&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ei=88aZVLbxKYf1UvO7gdAP&ved=0CBsQgQMwAA

Comment: @Sofia Thanks. Of course. I don't want to know about the GW(+) process. As it says above, I want to know about the mathematical/physics treatment of delayed supercriticality, in systems undergoing fission. The GW process is simply one way to approach this. (+)unless GW is the *only* way to approach this.